# How does the const variable 'count' gets updated when using useState() hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

const countHandler = () => {
   setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
}

return (
    <div className={styles.testclass}>
        <h2>Count Value {count}</h2>
        <button onClick={countHandler}>Update Count</button>
    </div>
)
```

Here the count is destructured as a **constant** value, so how will it change the value using the setCount

Comment: In case of function components, that function executes during every render. So the variable `count` is created in each render with the value from previous render that `useState` had stored.

Comment: @Nisarg you should add that as an answer - to me it's a good question and good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of function components, that function executes during every render. So the variable `count` is created in each render with the value from previous render that `useState` had stored.

Comment: I will add references from official documentation if I can find.

Comment: This is briefly explained [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component) and [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks)